# Copy text from form to another website's textfield

Tags: javascript, html, textfield

I have a form in which the user enters numbers in a field and then the page is directed to a url, the code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tracking</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function gotopage(){

                window.open("http://www.track-trace.com/aircargo");

        }
    </script>
    <form method="get">
        Search:
        <input id="input1" type="search" size="50" placeholder="Enter the number">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="gotopage();">
    </form>
</body>
```

Is there a way to fill up a particular field on the website which the script is directing to, which is:

```
<input type="text" name="number" id="number" maxlength="40" class="form-control input-lg" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, unless you can add code to the target site or the target site accepts parameters. Alternative is to create a proxy.

That said, If you look at the code of their form, they have the message

> <!-- Want to put this tracking on your website/intranet? Please use https://connect.track-trace.com/ -->

Their terms state clearly that the above is what you need to do:

> - You must not modify, adapt or hack the Service or modify another website so as to falsely imply that it is associated with the Service, Webfokus, or any other Webfokus service.
> - You agree not to reproduce, duplicate, copy, sell, resell or exploit any portion of the Service, use of the Service, or access to the Service without the express written permission by Webfokus.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it only if you have access to the implementation of the website you are redirecting to, so that you can use extra parameters.

Alternatively if you want this behavior specific to your own browser, you can some script or plugin to do that.